# Using css-modules with scss in react-app?

Tags: reactjs, sass, css-modules

I'm trying to use css-moduls and scss in react-app, but for some reason the styles are not added, although the class is found and rewritten to normal css. Moreover, the option with "className={styles['app-list-item-label']}" works, but "className={styles['btn-star']}" does not. node-sass installed.

```
.app-list-item {
 font-size: 1.25rem;
 .btn-star {
    color: red;
 }
 &-label {
    color: black;
 }
}
```

"app-list-item-label" becomes "post-list-item_app-list-item-label__RadS+" and has styles, and "btn-star" becomes "post-list-item_btn-star__XPkK6", however the styles are lost. I obviously do not understand something, so I ask you to explain how to use it all correctly together. (And is it worth it)
Just in case, I'll add the js part. I cut out everything superfluous so as not to distract.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import styles from './post-list-item.module.scss';

export default class PostListItem extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <span 
          className={styles['app-list-item-label']}>kva</span>
        <button type='button' 
                className={styles['btn-star']}>star</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Try adding first root class then extension class, like so: `className={styles['app-list-item btn-star']}`

Comment: Tried in first hour. Did not work.

Comment: Try the second approach `className={`${styles['app-list-item']} ${styles['btn-star']}`}`

Comment: I resigned myself and decided to use one thing. And in my case it will be scss.